# Change father and child places in a binary tree

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree

So, what I want to do is check whether an int within a complete binary tree leaf is bigger than that of its father and using that as a criterion have it change places with its father continuously all the way to the root. The thing is, it segfaults when it has to compare and change places with the root; if I make the loop stop before then, it works just fine(I think). Am I missing something obvious here?

```
typedef struct tnode *Treeptr;

typedef struct tnode {
    float owed;
    long afm;   

    Treeptr father;
    Treeptr left;
    Treeptr right;
} Treenode;
```

The following take place when a new leaf is added. I've omitted the part where the leaf is actually added to the tree because it works fine and is quite lengthy. The pointer p points to the last leaf inserted before the loop starts. The root's father and the leaves' children are initialized as NULL.

```
static int depth = 1;       
static int nodes_number = 0;        
int i;
Treeptr temp, temp2;

if(nodes_number == pow(2, depth) - 1)  
    depth++;            
nodes_number++; 

for(i=1 ; i<depth ; i++) {      
    if(p->owed > p->father->owed) { 
        temp = p->father;
        p->father = temp->father;
        if(temp->father != NULL) {
            if(temp == temp->father->left)
                temp->father->left = p;
            else
                temp->father->right = p;
        }   
        if(p == temp->left) {
            temp->left = p->left;
            p->left = temp;
            temp2 = p->right;
            p->right = temp->right;
            temp->right = temp2;                
        }
        else {
            temp->right = p->right;
            p->right = temp;
            temp2 = p->left;
            p->left = temp->left;
            temp->left = temp2;
        }           
    }
    else
        break;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the code for your structure definition, and where your variables are declared and initialized?

Answer (score 1):

In the case when `i=1`, p points to the root node and p->father may be a wild pointer or an uninitialized pointer.
So, when you execute the line

```
if(p->owed > p->father->owed) {
```

p->father cannot be dereferenced and will show segmentation fault.

I think changing the line to

```
if( (p->father!=NULL) && (p->owed > p->father->owed) ) {
```

will solve it.

Comment: Hmmm, like that it doesn't show segfault but it still doesn't work quite right. It's hard to explain, it seems like the tree shrinks down to 2 nodes, the new root and the previous root.

Comment: please specify the initial value of `p`.